# How do I keep scale for sublayer in scaled CALayer

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiscrollview, catiledlayer

I want to create original map as CATiledLayer.
Layer hierarchy　is like this above.

```
Map View (CATiledLayer)
----------------------
|  Pin (CALayer)     |
|  +-------+         |
|  | image |         |
|  +-------+         |
|                    |
|     Pin (CALayer)  |
|     +-------+      |
|     | image |      |
|     +-------+      |
|                    |
----------------------
```

Some 'Pin layer' are put on map view.

When zoom map, pin will zoom with map view.
But I want to keep zooming pin layer, like original Map app in iOS.

Anybody knows good answer?

Answer (score -1):

Have you set autoresizesubviews for the CATiledLayer?

```
[MapView setAutoresizesSubviews:YES];
```

Then make sure the Pins have been set with setAutoresizingMask

```
[PinView setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight |UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth];
```

You may need to set the margins too for the PinView to keep it in the right place.

Hope this helps.